# CanExecute method going to false problem

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

Well, in our application this usually works fine. But at some point, none of the CanExecute methods fire (even if I explicitly call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(), the CanExecute methods don't run). Anyway, despite the fact that they don't run, they all get set to false, so every button, menu item, etc, bound to a CommandBinding, gets disabled until I click the MainWindow.

Now, I suspect another Window causing this, when we do a certain action, a Window pops up, and then after the next action, all the buttons become disabled, without going through the CanExecute method.

Has anyone seen such a behavior? Any suggestion on how to solve this, is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some code ? What ICommand implementation are you using (DelegateCommand, RelayCommand...) ?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque Fixed the problem. It was some focus issue, not exactly sure why it made that happen, but removing it makes it work fine. Thanks!

Comment: I also had similar issues with focus and commands being disabled... But I eventually abandoned that project, so I never really tried to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It was related to the other window I mentioned, but it wasn't exactly that. The problem was that we had a method to hide the mentioned window, in that method, we gave focus back to the main window, and THAT was the problem. Not sure how or why, but removing the

```
App.MainWindow.Focus()
```

Line fixed this problem. So, whenever you close or hide a child window, do not call the Focus() method on your Main one.

Thanks!